# Python: IOError: missing arguments in invokation

Tags: python, python-2.7, ioerror

I am trying to import a module and create an object of its class as follows:

```
>>> import scriptsim
>>> scriptsim.Simulator()
```

But am getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: missing arguments in invokation
```

NOTE: As could be seen, `scriptsim` is properly installed, since no error is raised while importing. And I used `help` command in following way to confirm that there are no required arguments for `Simulator` method.

```
>>> help(scriptsim.Simulator)
```

Can anyone please help me understand what could be the reason for this error.
Thanks !!

Comment: Does the constructor for Simulator take any arguments? If yes, you might be missing those.

Comment: Try storing it to a variable. Create an object, <blockquote>sim = scriptsim.Simulator()</blockquote>, like the documentation shows.

Comment: This would be very bizarre for a standard python module. It turns out that `scriptsim` is an extension module and this exception is raised in `agent_python.c`. You may already have the source on your pc, or the download [is here](http://www.nelsim.com/scriptsim/download_v101.html). I haven't figured out the exact problem but it looks like args are required in there somewhere.

Comment: @RohitKumar, the constructor doesn't take any arguments as mentioned in the question

Comment: @tdelaney, I am new to scriptsim. Irony is that I am just trying the basic example & got stuck with this error. I have the source but am not able to figure out why this issue is being raised when Simulator doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: @user3503560 That puts you one step ahead of me! I just downloaded the source to poke around. The initializer takes no argument but Its raising the error when trying to open display and simulator. Maybe the config isn't right or it can't find the non-python simulation stuff.

Comment: @tdelaney, Am not able to understand where to head to. Tried looking into code in agent_python.c but could find no clue. Are you aware of any other Verilog to Python PLI similar to ScriptSim ?

Answer (score 1):

`scriptsim` is a C extension module so exception and traceback information is only available to the extent that the module wants to give it to you. Your problem is that this module needs to be configured and it actually pulls its configuration from the program command parameters (sys.argv). This is evil.

But if you look at its `python_agent.c` ([download and uppack here](http://www.nelsim.com/scriptsim/download_v101.html)), you see:

```
    Py_GetArgcArgv (&argc, &argv);
    if (argc < 5) {
            PyErr_SetString (PyExc_IOError,
                                             "missing arguments in invokation");
            fatal_error = 1;
            return -1;
    }
    {
            int tcp_port, read_fn, reg_num;
            const char *error_msg = NULL;
            if (sscanf (argv[3], "%d", &tcp_port) != 1) {
                    PyErr_SetString (PyExc_IOError,
                                                     "invalid argv[3] in invokation");
                    fatal_error = 1;
                    return -1;
            }
            if (sscanf (argv[4], "%d", &read_fn) != 1) {
                    PyErr_SetString (PyExc_IOError,
                                                     "invalid argv[4] in invokation");
                    fatal_error = 1;
                    return -1;
            }
            if (sscanf (argv[5], "%d", &reg_num) != 1) {
                    PyErr_SetString (PyExc_IOError,
                                                     "invalid argv[5] in invokation");
                    fatal_error = 1;
                    return -1;
            }
```

Assuming you know what `tcp_port`, `read_fn` and `reg_num` are, you can feed the module what it needs by setting up your own `sys.argv` before the first call. These are argument strings so convert `int` and etc.. as needed.

```
# copy args and configure simulator
argv = sys.argv
try:
    sys.argv = [argv[0], 'dummy', 'dummy', tcp_port, read_fn, reg_num]
    sim = scriptsim.Simulator()
finally:
    sys.argv = argv
```